# How to import R into Android project?

Tags: java, android, import

I've downloaded a couple of example Android projects to learn [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/). I constantly get this error saying `R cannot be resolved to a variable`. So I just do a CTRL+Shift+O to automatically import all dependencies. This then inserts `import android.R;` which unfortunately doesn't solve the problem.

Since the package name is `com.test;` I tried to do `import com.test.R;` but that doesn't work either.

Does anybody know how I can solve this?

Comment: do not import android.R, remove this and make a clean and build

Comment: @sunil - I did. I removed android.R, but on the lines where R is called it simply says "R cannot be resolved to a  variable". Any other suggestions?

Comment: did you updated rev 22 recently ? can you try restart the eclipse ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the next steps (order doesn't matter) :

1. update ADT & SDK , Eclipse and Java
2. remove gen folder , and create it again .
3. do a clean-project.
4. right click the project and choose android-tools -> fix-project-properties .
5. right click the project and choose properties -> java-build-path -> order-and-export. make sure the order is :

   - Android 4.3 (always the latest version)
   - Android private libraries
   - android dependencies
   - your library project/s if needed
   - yourAppProject/gen
   - yourAppProject/src
6. make sure all files in the res folder's subfolders have names that are ok : only lowercase letters, digits and underscore ("_") .
7. always make sure the targetSdk (in the manifest) is pointed to the latest API (currently 18) , and also set it in the project.properties file